# Adding another list of fields in a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that adds a new user into the database. It all works perfectly, but what I want is to be able to add more than one user at a time, so when I click to "Add another user", it would appear another list of fields for adding a user. I don't know exactly how to explain it so I'll add some pictures:

Here is what I have when I try to add a user:

[image: Adding one user]

And, what I want is that when I click on "Add another user", to show me another list of fields under the other, like this:

[image: Adding two users]

So, if I click five times, it would show me five "forms" and the original one:

[image: Adding five users]

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019095/adding-a-field-to-a-form-jquery) where it shows how to do it with a different example, but my code has a table and a form so I don't know much exactly how to do it. Here's my form code:

```
<table id="minimalist-table">
    <tr><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Mail</th><th>Language</th><th>Sex</th></tr>
    <form method="post" action="?action=users&sa=add">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="username[]" required="required"></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password[]" required="required"></td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email[]" required="required"></td>
    <td><select name="language[]">
    <option value="en_US">English</option>
    <option value="es_ES">Spanish</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><select name="sex[]">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td></tr>
    </form></table>
```

I have the values with arrays (like `name="email[]"`) because it's the way I can handle multiple elements for the database...

I've tried to put all this code into a function, so when I call the function it adds another group of fields into the form, but I don't know how to do it with JavaScript...
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092894/adding-new-rows-to-table-on-clicking-button-in-jquery

Comment: Thanks, @Mohsin ! It worked perfectly... I followed the steps in the question you gave me and it's all right!

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I usually create a hidden "template" element/row containing the HTML that should be added:

```
<table id="minimalist-table">
...
<tr class="template" style="display:none">
... all fields ...
</tr>
<tr class="submit_row"><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"> </td></tr>
```

So in the javascript you can do this to get the HTML (and disable the hidden inputs):

```
var row_template = $('#minimalist-table > .template').html().find(':input').prop('disabled', true)
```

The finished code would look something like this (untested)

```
var row_template = $('#minimalist-table > .template').html()
$('#add_row').on('click', function(){
    $('#minimalist-table .submit_row').before(row_template);
});
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted? Can you please accept an answer?

Comment: Well, not exactly... I used the solution of the comment in the main answer and it worked perfectly!